# maven dependencies-only jar

Tags: java, maven

I am working on a java project that is build using maven. 
The project has several dependencies, I am looking for a way to package my project into two jars - one for the actual project classes and the other for all the dependencies together.

I searched and found about the maven shade plugin which can produce a single jar with dependencies. So, as a workaround I created another module with no sources and link my pom to this module - then using the shade plugin I can generate one jar with all my dependencies. But this feels like the wrong way, is there any better way?

Comment: You could do the same with a multi-module project (rather than 2 projects).

Comment: @vikingsteve, sure - this is what I done, when I said 2 projects I actually meant two modules - I will update my question. It still feel a bit hackish though..

Comment: It feels hackish because it almost is. But... why do you take this approach? Are you forced to or did you choose to? If you explain more about *why* it's organised this way perhaps we can suggest an alternative

Comment: @vikingsteve, I am working on a project where we have many dependencies that are almost not changing but we have a system that - every time I package the project - automatically push the result to a remote server. I want to compare the dependencies md5 with the md5 in the server so that I will  only push the dependencies jar if it changed..

Comment: Ok. One more question - how many projects depend on the dependencies jar that you are building - one or many?

Comment: @vikingsteve, currently only one module, why?

Comment: Because I could suggest a similar solution, with 2 maven projects. The first one defines all your dependency versions in `<dependencyManagement>` which you use to define the versions. The second project depends on the first one and when you build it, it will have the correct versions. Not sure if this is applicable for you, but I work with a project set up in this manner

Comment: Another suggestion. You could look at OSGi based frameworks, like Fuse Fabric.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout maven assembly plugin here http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

You can have managed dependency set in assembly descriptor. 

And yes @vikingsteve's suggestion is also right.

Comment: I'm probably missing it, but where does it say that it allows in the descriptor to set that all the dependencies required for a project are packaged into a separate jar file rather than the main project?

Comment: @Shubham Chaurasia, can you elaborate on how to achieve what I want using the assembly plugin? I looked at the documentation and didn't find the relevant parts.. Thanks.