# How to tell Maven to re-package all dependencies into a single jar file

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

Given a pom.xml file with a list of dependencies, is there a Maven command to bundle all those jars into one big jar? **I don't want to include my .class files in the build** - I only want to include the libraries .class/jar files in the build - is there a way to do this?

I see this plugin around:

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/Crunchify/lib</outputDirectory>
                <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

1. I can't figure out where it's copying the dependencies to - even if I hardcode a path instead of `${project.build.directory}/Crunchify/lib`, nothing gets written to that location,
2. I assume that it's copying jars, but not putting the contents of multiple jars into one big jar file.

I also see this common plugin:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

```
     <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
            <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

but when I run `mvn clean package` with the `maven-assembly-plugin` present in pom.xml, I am not seeing any new jar file(s).

Comment: this is similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642087/maven-dependencies-only-jar

Comment: maven-shade-plugin (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) is the way to go. It can handle all the weird cases that come up when you are combining jars (e.g., merging of meta data).

Comment: @Rob thanks, can you show an example of packaging only dependencies and not user/project classes?

Comment: To help understand what a good solution might be, could you please explain why you don't want your classes in the resulting JAR?

Comment: @dnault it might not matter for what I am doing - I can't tell yet - but if you can show an example of how to put all my .classes in a jar with deps and/or just create a .zip file or jar with only the deps, both would help

Comment: I don't understand this part: I don't want to include my .class files in the build. Do you need to create a jar file with others jars files inside? Do you need a folder with all dependencies of your project? Do you need to generate an executable jar?

Comment: The reasoning is the dependencies are static (until dependency is added or versions change) but my project's files are dynamic - I want a static jar file that I don't have rebuild everytime and then another jar that represents my classes or whatever

Comment: sry, Alex, (1.) cannot reproduce! copies like charm (not to one jar but to `/Crunchify/lib`)

Comment: `${project.build.directory}` is normally the `target` folder ...

Answer (score 0):

Wit `jar-with-dependencies` and `single~package`, You trapped into one of assembly's "GOTCHAS" (there is nothing to assembly before package (is not completed)).

But Combining both plugins, this will work:

#### /pom.xml

```
<project>
   ...
    <!-- many many dependencies -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-deps</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

#### /src/assembly/assembly.xml

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">
  <id>big-big-jar</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.directory}/dependency</directory>
      <outputDirectory />
      <includes>
        <!-- attention: maybe you need more ... zip, tz.gz.bz. -->
        <include>*.jar</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

#### cmd

```
mvn clean package
...
BUILD SUCCESS
```

...will produce you a:

#### /target/${build.finalName}-big-big-jar.jar

..file, containing all transient dependencies *without* your .jar/classes.